# How do I send files with AirDrop in iOS 7 without using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios7, airdrop

Is it possible to use AirDrop in the iOS 7 SDK without UIActivityViewController? Right now I don't use UIActivityViewController but I want to include AirDrop as an option.

Comment: You cannot at this point `In iOS 7, AirDrop lets you share photos, documents, URLs, and other types of data with nearby devices. AirDrop takes advantage of peer-to-peer networking to find nearby devices and connect to them. Apps that include support for sending or receiving files and data automatically gain support for AirDrop.`

Comment: I guess I'll just have an AirDrop icon that shows an Activity view with just AirDrop. Hmmmmm....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `UIActivityViewController`, then exclude everything but airdrop.

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

// Exclude all activities except AirDrop.
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

// Present the controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```